# PHP autoload function

Tags: php, function, autoload

I would like to autoload functions, not classes. The error:

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare proba() (previously declared in /var/www/localhost/proba-function.php:5) in /var/www/localhost/proba-function.php on line 7

The index.php code:

```
class ASD {
    function __construct () {
        self::proba();
    }

    public static function __callStatic ( $name, $arguments ) {
        $foo = false;
        $directories = array_diff ( scandir ( __DIR__ ), array ( '..' ) );

        foreach ( $directories as $directory ) {
            $directory = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $directory;
            if ( is_dir ( $directory ) ) {
                $file = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . strtolower ( $name ) . '-function.php';
                if ( file_exists ( $file ) ) {
                    include ( $file ); // It's ok.
                    if ( function_exists ( $name ) ) {
                        $foo = true;
                        call_user_func_array(array('ASD', $name), $arguments); // It's not work.
                        break;
                    } else {}
                } else {}
            } else {}
        }

        if ( $foo === FALSE ) {
            $this -> error ( NULL, $name );
        } else {}
    }
}
```

The proba-function.php:

```
function proba () {
    print 'foo';
}
```

Comment: Besides removing the empty `else` statements, I would also add a `return` statement before `call_user_func_array` so you can get the return value of your function and remove the `break`

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing your `include()` calls with `include_once()`, so that the same files does not get included multiple times.

To be sure that the file is actually included, maybe you could consider using `require_once()` instead of a simple `include_once()`.

See also the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Maybe even 'require_once' as those functions seem to be crucial for the application.

Comment: Good suggestion! Just updated my answer =)